# does the R programming language have reflection?

Tags: r, reflection, metaprogramming, computer-science

Does R have reflection?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)

basically what i want to do is this:

```
currentRun = "run287"
dataFrame$currentRun= someVar;
```

such that `dataFrame$currentRun` is equivalent to `dataFrame$run287`.
This hasn't prevented me from solving any problems, but from an academic standpoint I would like to know if R supports reflective programming. If so, how would one go about using reflection in the example given?
Thank you!

Comment: This is not what I would describe as reflection.

Comment: Yes,thank you for bringing this to my attention. Perhaps I am confusing type introspection with variable interpolation, which I thought was still considered reflection?

Comment: here's a blog on reflection in R from a few days ago: http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/07/17/the-method-in-the-mirror-reflection-in-r/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, R supports reflective programming.

here is an R version of the example:

```
foo <- function()1

# without reflection
foo()

# with reflection
get("foo")()
```

probably such as `get`, `assign`, `eval` is relevant. see online helps of them.

Answer (score 6):

The use of the "$" operator should be discouraged in programming because it does not evaluate its argument, unlike the more general "[["

```
currentRun = "run287"
dataFrame[[currentRun]]= someVar   # and the";" is superflous

> dat <- data.frame(foo = rnorm(10), bar = rnorm(10))
>  myVar <- "bar2"
> bar2 <- 1:10
>  dat[[myVar]] <- bar2
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ foo : num  -1.43 1.7091 1.4351 -0.7104 -0.0651 ...
 $ bar : num  -0.641 -0.681 -2.033 0.501 -1.532 ...
 $ bar2: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Which will succeed if the properties (in particular length) of myVar are correct. It would not be correct to say the datFrame$currentRun is equivalent to dataFrame$run287, but is is correct that character variables can be interpreted as column names. There is also a eval(parse(text="...")) construct, but it is better to avoid if possible.

Comment: Could you provide more detail what you meant by "because it does not evaluate it's argument"?

Comment: When you enter dfrm$colm2, the interpreter will only see if there is a column named "colm2", whereas if you enter dfrm[[colm2]] the interpeter will find out what colm2's value is .. i.e it gets "evaluated" and then that value (whatever it might be) is used to see if there is a column by that name in dfrm. (And the same applies to lists that are not dataframes.) You can still use [["colm2"]] if there really is a column by that name.

Comment: @DWin: I'm not entirely convinced that `$` should be discouraged.  I find `dat$foo` a little cleaner to read than `dat[["foo"]]`.  As you mentioned, `[[` is more general, so e.g., `dat[[paste(letters[c(6, 15, 15)], collapse = "")]]` is okay, but `dat$paste(letters[c(6, 15, 15)], collapse = "")` is nonsense.  However, when `$` can be used, perhaps it should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully grasped the wikipedia article, but does indexing with `[` achieve your desired result? A trivial example:

```
> dat <- data.frame(foo = rnorm(10), bar = rnorm(10))
> myVar <- "bar"
> dat[ , myVar]
 [1]  1.354046574  0.551537607  0.779769817  0.546176894 -0.194116973  0.959749309
 [7] -1.560839187 -0.024423406 -2.487539955 -0.201201268
```

or

```
> dat[ , myVar, drop = FALSE]
            bar
1   1.354046574
2   0.551537607
3   0.779769817
....
```